# dropzone remove exif data before upload

Tags: javascript, dropzone.js

I'm working in a image uploader using dropzone.js. Images are posted to my backend by a route protected by AWS WAF.

The problem is that WAF is blocking many images because it detect some kind of sql code in the exif data.

After hours of reading, I figure out that I need to remove the exif data before upload the images.

Currently I'm stripping the exif data in my backend after upload, so remove it before upload should not be a problem.

Do you know a way to do this with dropzone?

This is how I initialized my dropzone

```
var myDropzone = new Dropzone("div#dZUpload", { 
        url: "{{ route('image.upload', $id) }} ",
        method: "post",
        autoProcessQueue: true,
        resizeWidth: 1920,
        resizeHeight: 1080,
        parallelUploads: 1
    });
```

Thank you guys!